# how to fetch current date time with utput file name using saxon9 command prompt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

i have a requirement in which every time output file name should be unique using Saxon command file .i thought to do using -now command but i am getting this error .i am getting the error like non numeric year component.please suggest me any solution .my command is

```
 java -jar saxon9pe.jar -now:yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+hh:mm input.xml input.xsl >output.xml
```

can i add timestamp at the end of output file.this command will run from window scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you either need to set the `now` option to a concrete value like `2013-08-26T12:00:00` or you can simply use `current-dateTime()` in the stylesheet to access the current date/time.

Comment: sorry i m very new to this.i want the above command run using batch file so it schedule daily basis so can i get diff -diff file name end with timestamp value.so everytime generated file is different.i cant chnage input and output file name. pls suggest me how to do that

Comment: Well on the command line you have specified `>output.xml`, that does not makes sense in my view if you want to have a different file name for the result with each run of Saxon. I would not specify `>output.xml` on the command line, instead inside the XSLT code I would use `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:result-document href="output{current-dateTime()}.xml"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:result-document></xsl:template>`.